# Is there any API to get a list of purchased/bought Apps for some Apple ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to find an API from Apple to get a list of purchased/bought Apps for some App ID (or for the already login Apple ID on the device). I prefer to retrieve the list of track ID's (not the apps' names) so I could search using: `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=<Track ID>`.

Comment: Not actually a dupe - this question is (implicitly) about purchases of other apps, not of IAP products for the current app.

Comment: @duskwuff Then je wuestion needs to be edited to make that clearer

Answer (score 0):

No. Absolutely not.

You can do that on your own machine — if your device is backed up there. But not on a users device, not for other apps.

And for good reason, I'd like to add. If you disagree, file an enhancement request

Alex